# Friction and damping properties not affecting physics body

Tags: ios, scenekit, game-physics

I am developing a mini golf game in Scenekit. I have applied dynamic physics body to the ball and static physics body to the grass surface and the brick walls show in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9KAM.png).

**Issue:**

When I apply the force to the ball, the ball’s linear and angular speeds change as shown in the graphs.  The ball’s speeds don’t reduce to zero (so that the ball can stop) but remains constant after certain value.

[Ball linear speed graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewBZQ.png)

[Ball angular speed graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUTjP.png)

**Analysis Tests:**

1. When I increase the values to both the [rolling friction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514737-rollingfriction) and the [friction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514794-friction), the ball speed is reduced quickly but remains constant after certain value (similar to the above graphs).
2. When I increase the values of the [linear damping](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514763-damping) and the [angular damping](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514792-angulardamping), the ball speed behavior is same as the point #1.
3. When I set the **gravity value** to -9.8 m/s2, the ball’s linear speed remains constant after 0.1 m/s. If I reduce the gravity value to -5 m/s2, the ball’s linear speed remains constant after 0.05 m/s.
4. The friction, linear friction, linear damping and angular damping are same throughout the motion of the ball.
5. There is 1 millimeter overlapping between the ball and the surface of the golf course.

**Questions:**

1. From the analysis **test #3**, I think the gravity is causing the constant ball speed issue. Is my assumption correct? If yes, how can I fix the issue? I can’t remove the gravity field as without the gravity field the ball will not roll along the grass and it will slide.
2. Why the friction and the damping properties are not affecting the ball speed after certain value?
3. Are there any other physics properties can cause such issue?
4. From the analysis test #5, are there any chances that the ball is receiving upward push to correct the position of the ball?

**Solutions:**

1. After reducing the gravity value to -1 m/s2 and [physics simulation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsworld/1512851-speed) speed to 4 (4 times fast physics simulation), the issue is fixed. However, I am worried that these settings will cause issues in further development of the game.
2. If I increase the **physics timestep** from **60 FPS to 200 FPS**, the issue is resolved. How solution 2 can fix this issue?

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: With regards to question 2 - it could be a floating point accuracy issue?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If you check the analysis test #3, the ball speed can go to the lower values such as 0.05 m/s. Hence, the friction and damping properties are affecting for the low ball speed values but somehow not making it zero.

Comment: It doesn't surprise me that there's issues in SCNPhysics. You're probably the first person to use it for mini-golf. I haven't even seen a billiards table exercise done with it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Are there any tests which I can perform to confirm that this is the physics engine's issue?

Comment: @Confused How solution 1 and 2 can fix this issue?

Comment: when you say "this" issue, which do you mean?

Comment: Sorry... I am referring to the issue mentioned in the "Issue" section.

Comment: I think you're going to have to make your own "sleep" function for physics bodies, and create opposing forces to slow balls to a full stop. Mirror the velocity with a force until the ball stops.

Comment: It truly baffles me that a combination of friction and rolling friction aren't giving you a fully stopped ball. That must be VERY annoying.